# WSE Server under Windows 2000

Tags: .net, windows-server-2000, wse

I have a problem with WSE on Windows 2000 Machines. The method SoapReceivers.Add crashed under Windows 2000. It seemes that the windows 2000 os did not allow to start a listening service on excluse addresses. So I find a out that I can set this in the config file to "false"

But the problem is still be available. Anybody with an idea..??

Greetings Kai..

Comment: WSE is obsolete. All new web service work should be done using WCF, and existing WSE code should be migrated or retired ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember there were a bunch of different WSE releases (1-3) & service packs. I know that the major releases where not backward compatible and release 2.0 had some internal incompatibilities between service packs. You may have a compatibility problem. Make sure that you've install the version that the app was written against.

If that's not the problem, then look at this [discussion thread](http://bytes.com/forum/thread376612.html). It might offer some clues. Good Luck!